# Select Option de blade en laravel para editar contenido

Tags: php, html, laravel, model-view-controller

Estoy tratando de editar mis usuarios segun el tipo de usuario será administrador o editor, desde el panel de administración el usuario admin puede cambiar el rol y asignar editor o administrador a otros usuarios.

En mi página de edición tengo un input ahora mismo donde el usuario puede colocar 0 o 1 dependiendo del rol que desea asignar.

> - 1 --> administrador
> - 0 --> editor (este se asigna por defecto a los usuarios    recien creados)

Este es el input actual:

```
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12">
            <div class="form-group">
                <strong>Tipo de usuario:</strong>
                <input type="text" name="tipo_usuario" class="form-control" value="{{ $user->tipo_usuario }}">
            </div>
        </div>
```

Por defecto al entrar siempre hay un valor ya asignado y que editamos el usuario, yo lo que pretendo es lo siguiente:

Crear un select option donde se muestren ambas opciones, editor y administrador y esté selecionada por defecto la opcion guardada para este usuario, para que cada vez que quiera editar algún dato y no quiera tocar el rol no sea necesario y este asignado ya por el valor recibido.

He intentado hacer lo siguiente, ya que en la base de datos debe recibir el numero 1 o 0, solo deseo que se lea visualmente la opción para que el usuario sepa el rol que elige:

```
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12">
            <div class="form-group">
                <strong>Tipo de usuario:</strong>
                <select class="form-control" name="tipo_usuario">
                    <option value="administrador"{{ $user->tipo_usuario == 1 ? 'selected' : ''}}>Administrador</option>
                    <option value="editor"{{ $user->tipo_usuario == 0 ? 'selected' : '' }}>Editor</option>
                </select>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Pero me da error y no se guarda correctamente.

> ParseError syntax error, unexpected '->' (T_OBJECT_OPERATOR),
> expecting ')' (View:rutadelavista/edit.blade.php)

Adjunto mi controlador:

```
public function edit(User $user)
    {
        return view('users.edit',compact('user'));
    }

    /**
     * Update the specified resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \App\Models\User  $user
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function update(Request $request, $id)
    {
        $request->validate([
            'name' => 'required',
            'surname' => 'required',
            'email' => 'required',
            'password' => 'required',
        ]);
  
        $users = User::find($id);
        $users->name = $request->get('name');
        $users->surname = $request->get('surname');
        $users->email = $request->get('email');
        $users->tipo_usuario = $request->get('tipo_usuario');
        $users->password = Hash::make($request->get('password'));
 
        $users->update();
 
        return redirect('/users')->with('success','Usuario actualizado correctamente.');
    }
```

y esta es la linea de la migración de la base de datos donde está el tipo de usuario:

```
$table->boolean('tipo_usuario')->default(0); //0 == editor  &&  1  == administrador
```

Comment: Tienes un error de sintaxis. No has cerrado algún paréntesis "(" pero si no pones ni el error ni la vista, imposible decirte donde

Comment: @ManuelRobles si ahi esta puesto el error y el trozo de código que he cambiado, he cambiado el input por el select option, con el input funciona correctamente, si pongo las lineas de código del select sale el error. Ambos codigos estan en mi pregunta.

Comment: Ni idea de laravel pero ese html no va a quedar bien formado; falta un espacio entre el value="admin" y el `selected` (que podría ser `selected="selected"`. No sabemos entonces qué viaja al controlador

Comment: Te falta hacer el `echo` de 'selected'

Comment: @JuanMartínPagella Me podrías decir donde debería colocarlo? o ponerme algun ejemplo mas conciso? gracias!

Comment: estoy probando el echo pero no se muy bien donde va, me da este error ParseError
syntax error, unexpected 'echo' (T_ECHO) (View: la vista) he colocado esto: echo ('selected' : '') y sin los parentesis tambien

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Al fin después de dos días he conseguido resolverlo, era una tontería pero como soy nueva en esto lo desconocía, el fallo era que el tratar con numeros el value debia ser un número y lo demás estaba correctamente puesto así quedaría el select Option:

```
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12">
            <div class="form-group">
                <strong>Tipo de usuario:</strong>
                <select class="form-control" name="tipo_usuario">
                    <option value="1"{{ $user->tipo_usuario == 1 ? 'selected' : ''}}>Administrador</option>
                    <option value="0"{{ $user->tipo_usuario == 0 ? 'selected' : '' }}>Editor</option>
                </select>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: Perdón @WinterIsback llegué tarde, tenés razón, el problema no es el echo. Pero tampoco es el valor del option value, por [documentación de HTML](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_option_value.asp) vos podés tener un valor de option value que no sea numérico. Me resulta más a que tu `tipo_usuario` no es de tipo numérico y por eso no te funcionaba bien la igualdad. Puede ser?